# MySql lookup and classification

Tags: mysql

given a test score => rank look up table

**lookup_table**:

```
score_min_inclusive   score_max_exclusive   class  
45                    67                    D  
67                    77                    C  
77                    82                    B  
82                    100                   A
```

**score_table**:

```
student_name    score   
zhang san       67   
Wang er         88  
Jack Ma         44  
LiLi Zhang      73
```

want to get such a table using MySQL
**rank_table**:

```
student_name   class  
zhang San      C  
Wang er        A  
Jack Ma        null  
LiLi Zhang     C
```

I tried using `CASE WHEN THEN`, but it did not work.
Does any body have good idea? Thanks very much.

regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a outer join:

```
select student_name,class 
from lookup_table right join score_table on score <  score_max_exclusive and score >=score_min_inclusive
```

Also see the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4a0f/6)